# Display related records, if they exist, in Rails view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

Is this much logic in view is justified to check for the presence of record?

```
# device model
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  validates :abbr, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true

  def abbr=(value)
    self[:abbr] = value.to_s.strip
  end
end
```

Here is the code for `DeviceVendor` that also saves `abbr` column of `Device` to uniquely identify the device:

```
# model code 
class DeviceVendor < ApplicationRecord
  validates :vendor, uniqueness: {scope: :device}
end

# controller code
def index
  @device_vendors = DeviceVendor.order(:device, :vendor)
end

# view code
<% @device_vendors.each do |device_vendor| %>
  <% device = Device.where(abbr: device_vendor.device).first %>
  <% vendor = Vendor.where(abbr: device_vendor.vendor).first %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= device.name if device %></td>
    <td><%= vendor.name if vendor %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', device_vendor %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_device_vendor_path(device_vendor) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

What is the rails way to do this?

Comment: What are the associations between `Device` and `DeviceVendor`?

Comment: Yes, it is too much logic in views.

Comment: @Pavan Currently `Device` has `abbr` column which will be unique and this will be saved in `DeviceVendor` not `device_id`

Comment: Just update the associations please

Comment: @devel check my answer, it will work.

Comment: If I understand correctly you try to achieve some nested form where drop-down is populated if there is particular value selected and 2nd drop-down shows appropriate values. If true, you might be interested in [this blog post](http://davidlesches.com/blog/rails-nested-forms-using-jquery-and-simpleform) or this one with [Cocoon gem example](https://www.sitepoint.com/better-nested-attributes-in-rails-with-the-cocoon-gem/). As guys below say - you don't do this complicated logic with Models and so in Views.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of ways to check the presence of an object, i prefer to use try :

```
device.try(&:name)
```

Comment: `try` doesn't accept a block, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `first_or_initialize`. It tries to find the record and, if not found, creates a new unsaved object (so that you always have an object and don't have to branch. This is called "confident code").

```
<% device = Device.where(abbr: device_vendor.device).first_or_initialize %>
<% vendor = Vendor.where(abbr: device_vendor.vendor).first_or_initialize %>
<tr>
  <td><%= device.name %></td>
  <td><%= vendor.name %></td>
```

Although I'm not a fan of queries in views like that. You should make proper activerecord relations there. Or, *at least*, move the queries to DeviceVendor's methods.

```
<td><%= device_vendor.device_or_default.name %></td>
<td><%= device_vendor.vendor_or_default.name %></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see three problems with this example.

#### 1. You are doing DB queries in the View template

A simple rule of thumb with Rails views: avoid triggering DB queries in your views at all costs.

The Rails convention is to do all your data preparation in the Controller, and your Views should only use what has already been gathered.

An exception to this rule is lazy-loaded data, but that would still be initialized somewhere else.

#### 2. You are performing queries in a loop

By performing a DB query inside a loop, you are generating far more requests than is likely necessary.

#### 3. You are (it appears) relying on a uniqueness constraint in the model

[Never rely on validation alone](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) to prevent duplicate records in your database. It is possible that you've already accounted for this and simply omitted the relevant code, but I want to make that point in case you haven't because it is important.

---

Honestly it seems like you should find a way to make `abbr` an actual foreign key so that you can rely on the framework to do lookups for you. Non-numeric keys are a thing. This looks like a standard many-many relationship, why are you reinventing the wheel here?

If that is not possible, here's how I would approach this:

**Controller**

```
def index
  @device_vendors = DeviceVendor.order(:device, :vendor)
  @devices        = Device.where(abbr: @device_vendors.map(&:device).uniq).index_by(&:abbr)
  @vendors        = Vendor.where(abbr: @device_vendors.map(&:vendor).uniq).index_by(&:abbr)
end
```

Using `index_by` in this way creates a Hash keyed to the `abbr` value. If `abbr` is non-unique and there are multiple records with the same value, this gets slightly more complicated but the principle is the same: pull in every record you need up front with as few queries as feasible.

**View**

```
<% @device_vendors.each do |device_vendor| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @devices[device_vendor.device].try(:name) %></td>
    <td><%= @vendors[device_vendor.vendor].try(:name) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', device_vendor %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_device_vendor_path(device_vendor) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Using [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) covers the case where the `abbr` key wasn't found.

Comment: "You are creating an n+2 query problem" - it's 2N + 1, actually :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I should have known invoking O-notation would bite me.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this much logic in view is justified to check for the presence of
>   record?

It is justified to check for a presence of a record in the view but you are writing *AR queries in the view* which will trigger *DB calls* and its not the *Rails way* to do it! You should instead move those to corresponding *view helper* or define it as *model methods*. I would do

```
#view_helper
def get_device_name_and_vendor_name(dv)
  device = Device.where(abbr: dv.device).first
  device_name = device.blank? ? nil : device.name
  vendor = Vendor.where(abbr: dv.vendor).first
  vendor_name = vendor.blank? ? nil : vendor.name
  return device_name,vendor_name
end
```

And in the view, call that method to get *device name* and *vendor name*

```
<td><%= get_device_name_and_vendor_name(device_vendor)[0] %></td>
<td><%= get_device_name_and_vendor_name(device_vendor)[1] %></td>
```

***Note:***
I would also instead apply associations to the models to cleanup those queries.

Comment: Can you also explain how association can be applied in this scenario as device_id is not getting used so that I can seed all the data to avoid association

Comment: @devel Associations  in your case is a long shot,since you need to add corresponding Foreign Key in the tables and the data in the db need to be altered too to map the corresponding records. But they provide more flexibility. My suggestion, take it or leave it :)

Comment: @devel: foreign key column does not _have_ to be `device_id`. You can customize it. Something along the lines of `belongs_to :device, foreign_key: :abbr`. Consult docs for the exact syntax.

Comment: @Pavan: you realize your proposed code makes 4 queries?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not sure how many queries it will make. I'm guessing 2. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Pavan: 2 queries per call. And you make two calls.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah right! I can't think of a way to make it simple. Also since the *divice name* and *vendor name* should be shown in two seperate `<td></td>`, I finally end up  with `get_device_name_and_vendor_name(device_vendor)[0]` and `get_device_name_and_vendor_name(device_vendor)[1]`

Comment: @Pavan: for simple, check my answer :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah! Since you already pointed out in your answer, I have to think of another way and the final result is *this answer* :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `try` method of ruby, exception will not be raised and `nil` will be returned instead, if the receiving object is a nil object.

Try below code in view:

```
# view code
<% @device_vendors.each do |device_vendor| %>
  <% device = Device.where(abbr: device_vendor.device).first %>
  <% vendor = Vendor.where(abbr: device_vendor.vendor).first %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= device.try(:name) %></td>
    <td><%= vendor.try(:name) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', device_vendor %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_device_vendor_path(device_vendor) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

OR correct way is to add association

```
Device has_many_and_belongs_to Vendor
Vendor has_many_and_belongs_to Device
```

DeviceVendor is Join table of Device and Vendor

Comment: So whats the difference between your answer and Othmane El kesri's answer?

Comment: @Pavan I am explaining whats the `try` method of ruby and how to use it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can still create relationships on keys that are not called `id` (although I wouldn't recommend it. I would recommend using `id`, at some point someone will want to change an abbreviation and it will not be easy. Joins on integers are also faster than joins on strings). I also suggest you name your join fields on `DeviceVendor` as `device_abbr` and `vendor_abbr` so that you can add logical relationships called `device` and `vendor` without causing a conflict.

If you want to join on abbreviation you can do something like:

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  validates :abbr, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :device_vendors, foreign_key: :vendor_abbr, primary_key: :abbr
  # You can do something similar with has_and_belongs_to_many

  def abbr=(value)
    self[:abbr] = value.to_s.strip
  end
end

class DeviceVendor < ApplicationRecord
  validates :device_abbr, presence:true
  validates :vendor_abbr, presence:true, uniqueness: {scope: :device_abbr}
  belongs_to :vendor, foreign_key: :vendor_abbr, primary_key: :abbr
  belongs_to :device, foreign_key: :device_abbr, primary_key: :abbr
end

# controller code
def index
  @device_vendors = DeviceVendor.order(:device, :vendor).include(:device, :vendor)
  # You could also simplify the above with a `scope` on DeviceVendor
end

# view code
<% @device_vendors.each do |device_vendor| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= device_vendor.device.name if device_vendor.device %></td>
    <td><%= device_vendor.vendor.name if device_vendor.vendor %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', device_vendor %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_device_vendor_path(device_vendor) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to add `device_name` and `vendor_name` methods to the `DeviceModel` and encapsulate that logic there.